# Ternary plot: points outside of the triangle

Tags: pgfplots, ternary-diagram

although my test data points are all inside the (0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0) triangle, my ternary plot unexpectedly plots some of them outside of the triangle.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}


\def\ternaryPlot#1{

 \begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{ternaryaxis}

        \addplot3 table[x index = 1, y index = 2, z index= 3]{#1};

        \end{ternaryaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{frame}

}

\begin{document}

\ternaryPlot{ternaryPlotTest.tsv}


\end{document}
```

ternaryPlotTest.tsv:

```
foo ololo   alala   elele
foo1    0.5 0.3 0.7
foo2    0.2 0.5 0.2
foo3    1   1   1
```

Comment: The components of each data point have to add up to the same value for all points, and these values have to work with the axis ranges. By default, the axis ranges are set to `0:1`. A point with the components `(1,1,1)` doesn't work in this configuration. What result are you expecting?

Comment: ... and neither do the others...

Comment: nvm, you are right about that :-/ It's just my test data and the assumption that they should be inside that are wrong.

Comment: @kutschkem: So I guess we can close this question then?

Comment: @Jake i do have another question concerning points outside of the plot, but i think we can close this one and i will open another one for the new question

Comment: @kutschkem: Actually, maybe it's best if you just put your `[Edit]` sentence as an answer to this question and accept it after the 24 hour waiting period. It could help someone else coming across the same problem.

Comment: 1 + 1 + 1 != 1 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the test points are **not** in the (0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0) triangle. All coordinates need to sum to 1 in order for the point to be inside the plot.